# How to move local to remote?

Tags: git

I have arrived in a situation like this:

```
* a77755f (HEAD, origin/dev) commit 1
| * d5ba4f1 (tag: 0.9.11.1, origin/master, master, dev) commit 2
| *  6e2a460 (tag: 0.9.11) Merge branch 'dev'
|/|   
* | e24ab63 commit 3
```

I am not really sure how; I thin I have done a commit (and push) on mater after merging and then someone has committed (and pushed) on dev and I do not how dev is near master on local. Can anyone help me to put dev local on origin/dev and then merge the master to dev for not loosing the commit 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you merge?

```
git checkout dev
git merge origin/dev # may need to resolve conflict
git checkout master
git merge dev        # fast-forward
```

Remember that merge conflicts are actually *good* in git. Since your history has unexpectedly diverged, the merge conflict will help you resolve all the differences.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout dev
git merge origin/dev`

This will merge remote branch with `commit 1` into your local branch dev with `commit 2`. Both commits will not be lost.